# how can I pass a value from parent component to directive in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

If I have the following line of code in my parent component

```
<input datepicker type="text" (change)="update($event)"/>
```

How can I pass a value to the datepicker directive?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html#!#unless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the input within the directive

**datepicker.directive.ts**

```
import {Input} from '@angular/core';
...
export class DatePickerDirective{
    @Input() config:any = {}; //set to default configuration
}
```

Now if you bind to the `config` property of this directive in the template, Angular will pass that value

**parent.component.ts**

```
dateConfig:any;
```

**parent.component.html**

```
<input datepicker type="text" [config]="dateConfig"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize it was the same as communicating between two components.

Comment: @ultimatecoder Remember that a Component is just a Directive with a template. They are essentially the same.