# How to read drop down list value from dialog box in angular 2

Tags: angular

I want to read value of drop down list from md dialog box. I unable to read it.
My code is:

right-panel-component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewContainerRef,ViewChild } from 
 '@angular/core';
import {MdDialog} from "@angular/material";
import {MdDialogRef} from "@angular/material";
import {ServersListDialogComponent} from "../servers-list-dialog/servers-
 list-dialog.component";
import {DownTimeGraphComponent} from "../down-time-graph/down-
 time-graph.component";
import any = jasmine.any;

@Component({
 selector: 'app-rightpanel',
 templateUrl: './rightpanel.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./rightpanel.component.css']
})
export class RightpanelComponent implements OnInit {
  receivedData:Array<any> = [];
  dialogRef: MdDialogRef<any>;
  componentData = null;

  constructor(public dialog: MdDialog) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  transferDataSuccess($event) {this.openDialog($event.dragData.valueOf().id);  }
 openDialog(id) {
 if(id>=1 && id<=8) {
  this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ServersListDialogComponent, {
    disableClose: false
  });
 } else {
  this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(LogDialogComponent, {
    disableClose: false
  });
 }

 this.dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {

  console.log('result: ' + result);
  console.log("after close dialog....");
  if(result == "yes") {
      if(graphName == "Down Time") {
        this.componentData = {
          component: DownTimeGraphComponent,
          inputs: {
            showNum: 9
          }
        };
      } 
  }
  this.dialogRef = null;
});
```

}
}

server-list-dialog.component.ts

```
import { Component,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MdDialogRef} from "@angular/material";
import {ServerItem} from '../server-item';
import {GetServersListService} from '../get-servers-list.service';
@Component({
 selector: 'app-servers-list-dialog',
 templateUrl: './servers-list-dialog.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./servers-list-dialog.component.css']
 })
 export class ServersListDialogComponent implements OnInit {
  serverItems : ServerItem[];
 constructor(public dialogRef: 
 MdDialogRef<ServersListDialogComponent>,private 
 service:GetServersListService) { }

 ngOnInit() {
   this.service.getServerItemList().subscribe(lst =>this.serverItems=lst);
}

}
```

server-list-dialog.component.html

```
<p>
  servers-list-dialog works!
</p>
Select server: <select name="serverid" id="server_list">
 <option *ngFor="let serverItem of serverItems" value="{{serverItem.id}}">
 {{serverItem.name}}</option>
</select>
<p></p>
<button type="button" (click)="dialogRef.close('yes')">Yes</button>
<button type="button" (click)="dialogRef.close('no')">No</button>
```

I want to read drop down list value in right-panel.component.ts file
I'm new in angular 2. Please give me solution how to read drop down list value from dialog box.

Comment: What does it mean when you say `read value of drop down list from md dialog box`? What I got from your problem is that you want the dropdown value from `server-list-dialog.component.ts` to `right-panel-component.ts`. Am I right?

Comment: @Aakash Thakur, I want the dropdown value from server-list-dialog.component.html to right-panel-component.ts file. Can we do like this?

Comment: Yes it is possible with property binding. Let me try it with an answer.

Comment: @Aakash Thakur, can you tell me where and what I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with property binding `[]`.

Try changing `server-list-dialog.component.html`-

```
<option *ngFor="let serverItem of serverItems" value="{{serverItem.id}}" [dropdownvalue]="serverItem">
```

Then you can declare an `Input` property in `right-panel-component.ts` like below:

```
export class RightpanelComponent implements OnInit {

@Input() dropdownvalue:any;
//Rest code remains the same
}
```

Be sure to import `Input` as `import { Input } from '@angular/core'`.

Comment: I didn't get what I need to here @Input() dropdownvalue:any; and getting for [dropdownvalue]="serverItem"

Comment: Its a way of passing data from one component to another(or from a parent component `server-list-dialog.component.ts` to a child component `right-panel-component.ts`). Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40144791/how-can-i-pass-a-value-from-parent-component-to-directive-in-angular-2?rq=1 and you will get an idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <select name="serverid" id="server_list [ngModel]="serverItems[0]">
          <option *ngFor="let serverItem of serverItems" [value]="serverItem.id">{{serverItem.name}}</option>
        </select>
```

try to modify your `html` code to this above.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But how to read this value in component?

Comment: You can use angular 2 form group class, then you will need to change `html` to :
<select name="serverid" id="server_list [ngModel]="serverItems[0]" formControlName="server">
please read the documentation about [FORMS](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html) and [form group](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroup-class.html)